# Detect if PATH has a specific directory entry in it

Tags: bash, shell, path

With `/bin/bash`, how would I detect if a user has a specific directory in their $PATH variable?

For example

```
if [ -p "$HOME/bin" ]; then
  echo "Your path is missing ~/bin, you might want to add it."
else
  echo "Your path is correctly set"
fi
```

Comment: Should the accepted answer be changed to the highly voted, bash builtin-based answer from @Gordon Davidson?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something really simple and naive:

```
echo "$PATH"|grep -q whatever && echo "found it"
```

Where whatever is what you are searching for. Instead of `&&` you can put `$?` into a variable or use a proper `if` statement.

Limitations include:

- The above will match substrings of larger paths (try matching on "bin" and it will probably find it, despite the fact that "bin" isn't in your path, /bin and /usr/bin are)
- The above won't automatically expand shortcuts like ~

Or using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -e 'exit(!(grep(m{^/usr/bin$},split(":", $ENV{PATH}))) > 0)' && echo "found it"
```

That still has the limitation that it won't do any shell expansions, but it doesn't fail if a substring matches. (The above matches "`/usr/bin`", in case that wasn't clear).

Comment: Matching to beginning/end of line and colons as in JasonWoof's answer takes care of your substring match limitation. Tilde expansion is not a common issue, since most people allow it to be expanded when assigned (e.g. `PATH="~/bin:$PATH"`) but can be taken care of with a substitution if necessary.

Comment: I'm using the grep solution wrapping the pattern with colons.

Comment: Inspired by your answer: 
if [ "$(readlink -f /etc/mtab | grep '\/proc\/'&& echo "found it")" ]; then
echo do something else
else
 echo do something differently
 fi

is the correct use of if as you mentioned?

Answer (score 184):

Using `grep` is overkill, and can cause trouble if you're searching for anything that happens to include RE metacharacters.  This problem can be solved perfectly well with bash's builtin `[[` command:

```
if [[ ":$PATH:" == *":$HOME/bin:"* ]]; then
  echo "Your path is correctly set"
else
  echo "Your path is missing ~/bin, you might want to add it."
fi
```

Note that adding colons before both the expansion of $PATH and the path to search for solves the substring match issue; double-quoting the path avoids trouble with metacharacters.

Comment: No need to quote inside `[[` and `]]`. Word splitting and pathname expansion do not happen there.

Comment: @bobbogo Quotes are needed on the right side of the `=` in case the directory contains any glob metacharacters (which would be unusual, but possible). It has no effect on the left side, but I prefer to just double-quote variables everywhere (unless there's a specific reason not to) instead of trying to keep track of all the weird rules about where it's safe or unsafe to leave them off (e.g. the right side of the comparison here).

Comment: @GordonDavisson You are right! Any glob patterns appearing in an expansion on the RHS of `==` (et. al.) are interpreted as such. Gosh you learn something every day on Stack. TVM

Comment: I believe this will fail if `$HOME/bin` is the first or the last path in `$PATH`

Comment: @MestreLion It should work properly even then; that's why the extra colons in `":$PATH:"` are needed.

Answer (score 23):

There is absolutely no need to use external utilities like `grep` for this.  Here is what I have been using, which should be portable back to even legacy versions of the Bourne shell.

```
case :$PATH: # notice colons around the value
  in *:$HOME/bin:*) ;; # do nothing, it's there
     *) echo "$HOME/bin not in $PATH" >&2;;
esac
```

Comment: This method is helpful if you have files that can be sourced from sh,ksh,bash,or zsh

Answer (score 19):

Here's how to do it without `grep`:

```
if [[ $PATH == ?(*:)$HOME/bin?(:*) ]]
```

The key here is to make the colons and wildcards optional using the `?()` construct. There shouldn't be any problem with metacharacters in this form, but if you want to include quotes this is where they go:

```
if [[ "$PATH" == ?(*:)"$HOME/bin"?(:*) ]]
```

This is another way to do it using the match operator (`=~`) so the syntax is more like `grep`'s:

```
if [[ "$PATH" =~ (^|:)"${HOME}/bin"(:|$) ]]
```

Comment: The `?(:*)` is an [extended glob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) pattern which needs to be explicitly enabled separately on most platforms (`shopt -s extglob`).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pure-bash implementation that will not pick up false-positives due to partial matching.

```
if [[ $PATH =~ ^/usr/sbin:|:/usr/sbin:|:/usr/sbin$ ]] ; then
  do stuff
fi
```

What's going on here? The =~ operator uses regex pattern support present in bash starting with version 3.0. Three patterns are being checked, separated by regex's OR operator `|`.

All three sub-patterns are relatively similar, but their differences are important for avoiding partial-matches.

In regex, `^` matches to the beginning of a line and `$` matches to the end. As written, the first pattern will only evaluate to true if the path it's looking for is the first value within $PATH. The third pattern will only evaluate to true if if the path it's looking for is the last value within $PATH. The second pattern will evaluate to true when it finds the path it's looking for in-between others values, since it's looking for the delimiter that the $PATH variable uses, `:`, to either side of the path being searched for.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the following shell function to report if a directory is listed in the current `PATH`. This function is POSIX-compatible and will run in compatible shells such as Dash and Bash (without relying on Bash-specific features).

It includes functionality to convert a relative path to an absolute path. It uses the `readlink` or `realpath` utilities for this but these tools are not needed if the supplied directory does not have `..` or other links as components of its path.  Other than this, the function doesn’t require any programs external to the shell.

```
# Check that the specified directory exists – and is in the PATH.
is_dir_in_path()
{
  if  [ -z "${1:-}" ]; then
    printf "The path to a directory must be provided as an argument.\n" >&2
    return 1
  fi

  # Check that the specified path is a directory that exists.
  if ! [ -d "$1" ]; then
    printf "Error: ‘%s’ is not a directory.\n" "$1" >&2
    return 1
  fi

  # Use absolute path for the directory if a relative path was specified.
  if command -v readlink >/dev/null ; then
    dir="$(readlink -f "$1")"
  elif command -v realpath >/dev/null ; then
    dir="$(realpath "$1")"
  else
    case "$1" in
      /*)
        # The path of the provided directory is already absolute.
        dir="$1"
      ;;
      *)
        # Prepend the path of the current directory.
        dir="$PWD/$1"
      ;;
    esac
    printf "Warning: neither ‘readlink’ nor ‘realpath’ are available.\n"
    printf "Ensure that the specified directory does not contain ‘..’ in its path.\n"
  fi

  # Check that dir is in the user’s PATH.
  case ":$PATH:" in
    *:"$dir":*)
      printf "‘%s’ is in the PATH.\n" "$dir"
      return 0
      ;;
    *)
      printf "‘%s’ is not in the PATH.\n" "$dir"
      return 1
      ;;
  esac
}
```

The part using `:$PATH:` ensures that the pattern also matches if the desired path is the first or last entry in the `PATH`. This clever trick is based upon [this answer by Glenn Jackman on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32054/22812).

Answer (score 1):

This is a brute force approach but it works in all cases except when a path entry contains a colon. And no programs other than the shell are used.

```
previous_IFS=$IFS
dir_in_path='no'
export IFS=":"
for p in $PATH
do
  [ "$p" = "/path/to/check" ] && dir_in_path='yes'
done

[ "$dir_in_path" = "no" ] && export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/check"
export IFS=$previous_IFS
```

Answer (score 0):

`$PATH` is a list of strings separated by `:` that describe a list of directories. A directory is a list of strings separated by `/`. Two different strings may point to the same directory (like `$HOME` and `~`, or `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/bin/`). So we must fix the rules of what we want to compare/check. I suggest to compare/check the whole strings, and not physical directories, but remove duplicate and trailing `/`.

First remove duplicate and trailing `/` from `$PATH`:

```
echo $PATH | tr -s / | sed 's/\/:/:/g;s/:/\n/g'
```

Now suppose `$d` contains the directory you want to check. Then pipe the previous command to check `$d` in `$PATH`.

```
echo $PATH | tr -s / | sed 's/\/:/:/g;s/:/\n/g' | grep -q "^$d$" || echo "missing $d"
```

Answer (score 0):

A better and fast solution is this:

```
DIR=/usr/bin
[[ " ${PATH//:/ } " =~ " $DIR " ]] && echo Found it || echo Not found
```

I personally use this in my bash prompt to add icons when i go to directories that are in $PATH.