# How to test in shell if a path is already inside environment $*PATH?

Tags: python, bash, shell, virtualenv

I am writing a script for a python (Django) app inside a virtualenv. Therefore, I need to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment.

I have been doing it very easily, like so:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGO_DIR:$PYTHONPATH
```

The problem is, when I start my script multiple times, I get the following :

```
$ env
[...]
PYTHONPATH=/home/achedeuzot/project:/home/achedeuzot/project:/home/achedeuzot/project:/home/achedeuzot/project:/home/achedeuzot/project:/home/achedeuzot/project:/home/achedeuzot/project:/home/achedeuzot/project:/usr/bin/python
```

As you can see, the same path gets concatenated many times because I don't check if it's already present. Is there a way for my bash script to test if a given path (here `/home/achedeuzot/project`) is already in the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` so I won't export it again ?

Thank you for your help !

**UPDATE** You could say "ok, that shouldn't really do any harm to have it multiple times", but actually it does because my django app says that there are multiple paths for a resource and it fails to load.

Comment: Pretty related: [Detect if user's path has a specific directory in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396066/detect-if-users-path-has-a-specific-directory-in-it) - not trying to close as duplicate because it would close directly

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find the right keywords to stumble on this other SO post ! Maybe mine will contain keywords that let other people find the other, answered one ;)