# gitlab ci scripts during which $? is allowed to be non-zero

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

In our project we have a shell script which is to be sourced to set up environment variables for the subsequent build process or to run the built applications.

It contains a block which checks the already set variables and does some adjustment.

```
# part of setup.sh
for LIBRARY in "${LIBRARIES_WE_NEED[@]}"
do
  echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH | \grep $LIBRARY > /dev/null
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
   echo Adding $LIBRARY
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$LIBRARY
  else
   echo Not adding $LIBRARY
  fi
done
```

i.e. it checks if a path to a library is already in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and if not, adds it.
(To be fair, this could be written differently [(like here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396066/detect-if-users-path-has-a-specific-directory-in-it), but assume the script is supposed to achieve something which is very hard to do without calling a program, checking `$?` and then either doing one thing or doing another thing).

The `.gitlab-ci.yml` then contains

```
before_script:
  - yum install -y <various packages>
  - source setup.sh
```

but the runner decides to stop the before script the very moment `$?` is non-zero, i.e. when the if-statement decides to add a path to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
Now it is nice that the gitlab runner checks `$?` after each line of my script, but here it'd be great if the lines in `.gitlab-ci.yml` were considered atomic.

Is there a way to avoid the intermediate checks of `$?` in a script that's sourced in `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

Comment: This question is relevant if you are getting `ERROR: Job failed: Process exited with status 1` without any other clue. Added comment for future searches.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `command_that_might_fail || true` to mask the exit status of said command.

Also note that you can use `grep -q` to prevent output:

```
echo "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" | grep -q "$LIBRARY" || true
```

This will however also mask `$?` which you might not want. If you want to check if the command exits correct you might use:

```
if echo "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" | grep -q "$LIBRARY"; then
  echo "Adding $LIBRARY"
else
  ...
fi
```

I suspect that `gitlab-ci` sets `-e` which you can disabled with `set +e`:

```
set +e # Disable exit on error
for library in "${LIBRARIES_WE_NEED[@]}"; do
  ...
done
set -e # Enable exit on error
```

Future reading: [Why double quotes matter](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and [Pitfalls with `set -e`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Answer (score 30):

Another trick that I am using is a special kind of "|| true", combined with having access to previous exit code.

```
- exit_code=0
- ./myScript.sh || exit_code=$?
- if [ ${exit_code} -ne 0 ]; then echo "It failed!" ; else echo "It worked!"; fi
```

The $exit_code=$? always evaluates to "true" so you get a non failing command but you also receive exit_code and you can do whatever you want with it.

Note please, that you shouldn't skip the first line or exit_code will be uninitialized (since on successful run of script, the or'ed part is never executed and the if ends up being)

```
if [ -ne 0 ];
```

instead of

```
if [ 0 -ne 0 ];
```

Which causes syntax error.

Comment: Note that you'll need to reset the variable everytime you need it, as the assignment will only happen if the command fails. Something like `exit_status=0; ./myscript.sh || exit_status=$?`

Comment: Please just make it a habit to always wrap  your parameter expansions in double quotes: `[ "$exit_status" -ne 0 ]` if the parameter is empty it will expand to an empty argument for the `[` command, instead of evaporating. It will also prevent word splitting and pathname expansion.