# Bash running multiple commands, until one fails while capturing last exit code

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci, exit-code

My question is partially answered here: [gitlab ci scripts during which $? is allowed to be non-zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39466770/314056)

In principle, I want to achieve the following in bash:

```php
// assume both functions return truthy values and the 2nd doesn't run if 1st fails

$success = test1() && test2();

someOtherStuff();

exit($success);
```

[GitLab CI scripts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#script) terminate immediately when any simple command fails (possibly due to [`set -e`](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/set-ex), IDK for sure).

The nearest (and taking that link into consideration):

```
CODE=0
if test1 && test2; then
    CODE=1
fi

someOtherStuff

exit $CODE
```

Is there any better way? In particular, I'd like to get the real `$CODE` not a fake one.

Comment: BTW, `set -e` is not particularly good practice -- see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, but what I mean is that it is enabled by default in GitLab CI (or something similar with that same behaviour) - it's not my decision.

Comment: Also, all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or system, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use. You should use such lowercase names in your own code, to avoid conflicting with system-meaningful variables which may be added in the future. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.

Comment: Yeah, bad habit mixing between uppercase vars required by applications (eg; behat's `BEHAT_PARAMS` etc) and vars for local use.

Comment: BTW, if you choose to, you can turn `set -e` off by putting `set +e` in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you're asking how to run a series of commands until one fails, and store the exit status of the failing command for future reference, in a manner which is robust against side effects of `set -e`.

Using `test1`, `test2` and `test3` as our commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

test1() { return 0; }
test2() { return 2; }
test3() { echo "THIS SHOULD NOT BE RUN"; }
someOtherStuff() { echo "This should be run; current value of retval is $retval"; }

retval=0
test1 && test2 && test3 || retval=$?
someOtherStuff ||: "ignoring a failure here"
exit "$retval"
```

`|| retval=$?` makes `test1 && test2 && test3` a *checked expression*, thus immune to `set -e`.

`:` is a synonym for `true`, with a history of conventional use as a placeholder.

---

Running the above, we have the following output:

```
This should be run; current value of retval is 2
```

...and the exit status of the script is indeed `2`.

Comment: Cool, wouldn't have thought about that last `||`... I'd have expected immediate termination.