# How to add to PATH without creating duplicates

Tags: bash, shell, path

I have a shell script that adds to the PATH in .bashrc, however every time the script is run it creates a duplicate, I'm wondering what the best way to check for a duplicate is before writing a new entry.

Comment: See ["Detect if PATH has a specific directory entry in it"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396066/detect-if-path-has-a-specific-directory-entry-in-it) and the superuser question ["Add directory to $PATH if it's not already there"](https://superuser.com/questions/39751/add-directory-to-path-if-its-not-already-there).

Comment: Did you close this? If so then it's really bloody unhelpful. The answers you pointed to have some of the information but certainly don't answer the question completely, as such you have managed to shut down the discussion before it was able to be completed, incredibly unhelpful and quite at odds with teh intent of the site.

Comment: If you think there is information missing that warrants re-opening the question then feel free to edit the question to explain what wasn't answered per the [reopen policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions).

Comment: The questing is correct now, it specifically asks about checking bashrc for a duplicate or overlapping entry before writing a new one, the answers cover how to check for an active path and have nothing about interacting with a file, an active discussion would have dealt with that, this is just a waste of time, assumption is a terrible form of communication, a simple question would have solved the issue

Comment: Your question is extremely ambiguous if that was your intention. Most people reading `I have a script that adds to PATH in .bashrc` are going to interpret that as bashrc calling a script that edits PATH rather than the script rewriting bashrc to change its PATH value. This is why, per [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), we recommend giving [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). They go a long way toward clarifying your intention.

Comment: And a discussion would have teased that out where slamming the question closed achieves nothing